# Перенос слов в input

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с затруднением переноса в `#textName,#textMail,#textMessage`, печатает в одну строку до посинения. Знаю что textarea помогает с этим делом но выглядит не так как хотелось бы :( Какие есть способы добавить перенос?

```css
.main-head form{
background-color: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
display: block;
height: 390px;
width: 375px;
margin-left: 150px;
box-shadow: 0px -20px 50px -10px #E0E0E0,
           -20px 0px 50px -10px #E0E0E0,
            20px 0px 50px -10px #E0E0E0;
text-align: center;
}
#textName,#textMail,#textMessage {  
display: fixed;
border:none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 15pt;
outline: none;
width: 295px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #C7C7C7;
border-bottom-width: 1.2px;     
}
#textName{
margin-top: 35px;
}
#textMail{
margin-top: 30px;
}
#textMessage{
height: 95px;
}

form p{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20pt;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form action="server">
    <p><samp>Send</samp> A Message</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name..." id="textName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your email..." id="textMail">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your message..." id="textMessage">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="messageButton">
</form>
```

Comment: в инпутах нет переноса, они однострочные. На то она и textarea.

Comment: А какой вы результат хотите сделать?

Comment: чтоб переносилось на нвоую строку по окончанию длины input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо инпутов однострочные `textarea` [с плагином Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/). Они будут выглядеть как инпуты, к которым добавляются строки при переносе или нажатии <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```js
autosize($('textarea'));
```

```css
.main-head form{
background-color: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
display: block;
height: 390px;
width: 375px;
margin-left: 150px;
box-shadow: 0px -20px 50px -10px #E0E0E0,
           -20px 0px 50px -10px #E0E0E0,
            20px 0px 50px -10px #E0E0E0;
text-align: center;
}
#textName,#textMail,#textMessage {  
display: fixed;
border:none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 15pt;
outline: none;
width: 295px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #C7C7C7;
border-bottom-width: 1.2px;     
}
#textName{
margin-top: 35px;
}
#textMail{
margin-top: 30px;
}
#textMessage{
height: 95px;
}

form p{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20pt;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form action="server">
    <p><samp>Send</samp> A Message</p>
    <textarea rows="1" placeholder="Your name..." id="textName"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="1" placeholder="Your email..." id="textMail"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="1" placeholder="Your message..." id="textMessage"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="messageButton">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/js/autosize.min.js"></script>
```